# How to get an array of all movies from themoviedb?

Tags: reactjs, themoviedb-api

I do not understand how to display all movies in an array. In console:

```
'index.jsx:14 GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/undefined?api_key=66eb3bde9cca0487f03e78b512b451e4 404
{success: false, status_code: 34, status_message: 'The resource you requested could not be found.'}'
```

My code is below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Main = () => {

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getRecipes()
    },[])

    const getRecipes = async (id) => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=66eb3bde9cca0487f03e78b512b451e4`
        );
        const data = await response.json()
        setRecipes(data.id)
        console.log(data)
    }
      
    return(
        <main></main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: id is not passed to `getRecipes`

Comment: Just _look_ at the URL: `/movie/undefined`?! Also note you now need to rotate your API key (which you shouldn't be including in client-side code for exactly this reason) because you've publicly shared it.

Comment: Hey.. don't put your valid api key here! Just put a sample or replace it with `API_KEY`

Answer (score 3):

#### I assume that you are looking for all movie list, not for a movie data. If that is what you meant be, then :-

##### As in the tmdb docs, you can discover movies, [docs.](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie-discover)

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Main = () => {

    const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getRecipes()
    },[])

    const getRecipes = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=<your_api_key>`
        );
        const data = await response.json()
        setRecipes(data.results) // `results` from the tmdb docs
        console.log(data)
    }
      
    return(
        <main></main>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt send an id to the getRecipes Function so it will cause an error,
because the id is undefined at your function.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes("2") //Here you should pass the id
},[])
```

Moreover , you imported axios without using it.

```
    const getRecipes = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/${id}?api_key=66eb3bde9cca0487f03e78b512b451e4`);
    const data = response.data;
    console.log(data);
}
```